# Why error message is displayed on console when controller throws a method supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I am writing integration test for a nodejs/sails js application, where I have an [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) controller method/route that throws error when input parameters are not provided.

I am using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to write integration test, everything works fine from my perspective, but when the test run error is written onto the console.

```
describe("a controller method", () => {
  it("should throw error message", () => {
    server('127.0.0.1')
    .get('url to getData')
    .set('Cookie', 'cookie token')
    .end((err, res) => {
      if(err) return done(err);
      //console.log(res);
      expect(res.status).to.equal(500);
      expect(res.body).to.have.property('error', 'Provide a jobName');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

This following piece of code works fine cause I wrap this within an anonymous function and expect that function to throw. But I am not sure how to assert against those error.

```
it("throws", () => {
      expect( function () {
        server('127.0.0.1')
      .get('some url')
      .set('Cookie', 'cookie token')
      }).to.throw;
    });
```

The controller code looks like following. This is the method that is being called when URL end is requested.

```
getData : async (req, res) => {

    let jobName = req.params.jobName || '',
        buildId = req.params.buildId || '';

    if(!jobName.trim() ){
      return res.negotiate({error:'Provide a jobName'});
    }

    if(isNaN(buildId)) {
      return res.negotiate({error:'Invalid build id supplied.'});
    }

    try {
      let rawResult = await getData(jobName, buildId);
      let promotions = formatData(rawResult);

      let result = {
        total : promotions.length || 0,
        items : promotions
      };
      return res.json(result);
    } catch(error) {
      sails.log.error(`Request Parameter: Job name = ${req.param('jobName')} & build id = ${req.param('buildId')}`);
      sails.log.error(error);
      return res.negotiate({error: sails.config.errorMessage});
    }
  }
```

Why is the error being written to console ? What am I doing wrong here? 
Any help/pointer is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending that error from express? In general express follows the way of passing errors rather than throwing it, for any errors in the program you can pass the error object to 'next' function. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

e.g

```
 app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

Comment: please see my update to question. FYI this is basically a Sails Js application that negotiates with error using  sails.negotiate().

Answer (score 0):

async returns a promise and although you have placed a try catch block, my guess is the error is not in the block. It is most likely due to the promise rejection not getting handled.

The below should be of help to you as applying to the sails context.

> since async functions return a promise, you need to .catch() any
>   promise rejections and pass them along to next(). Express error
>   handlers are only triggered by errors passed to next(), not exceptions
>   that you throw. [Source](http://thecodebarbarian.com/using-async-await-with-mocha-express-and-mongoose)

And for [promise()=> reject](http://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js)

Comment: How is it possible ?  I checked that method is being called, if you see I get the error object added to console. Please see the screen shot attached to the question.

Comment: What are you trying here? The screenshot is obviously different from what the describe message says.

Comment: Sorry , the getData method is actually the code from another method I pasted it here in a hurry, I am changing it now. But the idea is the request hit that method and the error should be thrown but shouldn't shown on the console.  The code just below the screen-shot is passes because the getData() throws error, but when we use Supertest with .end((err, res) => {}) it acutally execute that method and error is thrown.